# expected value of order statistic

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

I am having troubles with solving this task

> **7.4.5.** Show that the first order statistic $Y_1$ of a random sample of size $n$ from the distribution having pdf
>   $$f(x;\theta) = e^{-(x-\theta)}, \theta<x<\infty, -\infty<\theta<\infty,$$
>   zero elsewhere, is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Find the unique function of this statistic which is the MVUE of $\theta$.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiqS9.png)

I showed completeness and sufficiency, but I cannot get $E[Y_1]$, to find MVUE. I want to use Sheffe Lehmann theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the random variables in question be $X_1$ to $X_n$.  Note that $Y_1\gt y$ if and only if all the $X_i$ are greater than $y$. Thus for $y\gt \theta$ we have
$$\Pr(Y_1\gt y)=(e^{-(y-\theta)})^n=e^{-n(y-\theta)}.$$
So for $y\gt \theta$ the cdf of $Y_1$ is $1-e^{-n(y-\theta)}$.

Now we can find the density of $Y_1$ by differentiating, and then find the expectation in the usual way.

But we really don't need to compute if we know the mean of the exponential distribution with parameter $n$. Recall this is $\frac{1}{n}$. For the mean of $Y_1$, shift right by $\theta$.

Comment: I messed up the most basic thing, took $Y_n$ instead of $Y_1$ and that's why I had the problem with further calculations