# Proof that a statistic is complete

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I need some help with this exercise:

The density function of the random variable $X_i$ is:

\begin{equation*}
f_\theta(x)=\exp(\theta-x)1_{[\theta,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation*}

The maximum likelihood function is:

\begin{equation*}
L(x,\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(\theta-x_i)1_{[\theta,\infty)}(x_i)=exp\bigg(n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)1_{[0,\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}]}(\theta)
\end{equation*}

And its (unique) maximum is attended for $\hat\theta_{ML}=\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

I find that the statistic $Y=\min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ is sufficient using the factorization theorem and I now have to prove that it is also complete.

First of all I've calculated the density of $Y$ which is:

\begin{equation*}
g_\theta(x)= n\exp(n\theta-nx)
\end{equation*}

Then for the definition of complete statistic I have to prove that :

\begin{equation*}
E_\theta(h(Y))=0 \Rightarrow h=0
\end{equation*}

and this implies that:

\begin{equation*}
E_\theta(h(Y))=\int_\theta^\infty h(y)n\exp(n\theta-ny)dy=0
\end{equation*}

How can I conclude from the last expression that $h(y)$ has to be zero $\forall y$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3315327/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(\theta)=\int_\theta^\infty h(y)e^{-ny}dy$ is identically zero $\forall\theta>0$.

$\implies f'(\theta)=-h(\theta)e^{-n\theta}=0$ which gives $h(\theta)=0$ over $\Bbb R^+$ so $P_\theta[h(x)=0]=1$.